# Command doesn't expand into other commands after string substitution

Tags: macros, luatex, xstring, easylist

The MWE should explain it all (use LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{easylist}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\hello}{ hello I am a mouse}
    \StrSubstitute{\hello}{ }{ § }[\ctext]

    This is to show that the substitute works:
    \ctext

    \vfill

    I can also use this text to make a list:
    \begin{easylist}
         § hello § I § am § a § mouse
    \end{easylist}

    \vfill

    But this does not work:
    \begin{easylist}
        \ctext
    \end{easylist}

    \vfill

    or this:
    \edef\hellot{\ctext}
    \begin{easylist}
        \hellot
    \end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

How can I keep commands in the substituted string, `\ctext`, so that the list is generated from `\hello`?

Comment: No need to load the `fontenc` package when using LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't work, because `easylist` makes `§` active only inside the `easylist` environment, but when you do the substitution the character `§` is *not* active, being outside an `easylist` environment.

You have to make the substitution in a setting where `§` is active and be careful not to expand it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{easylist}
\begin{document}

\begingroup\catcode`§=\active
\newcommand{\hello}{ hello I am a mouse}
\noexpandarg
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\hello}{ }{ § }[\temp]
\global\let\ctext\temp
\endgroup

This is to show that the substitute works:
\texttt{\meaning\ctext}

\bigskip

I can also use this text to make a list:
\begin{easylist}
 § hello § I § am § a § mouse 
\end{easylist}

\bigskip

Also this works:
\begin{easylist}
\ctext
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\noexpandarg` and `\expandafter` you can do

```
\begingroup\catcode`§=\active\let§\relax
\newcommand{\hello}{ hello I am a mouse}
\StrSubstitute{\hello}{ }{ § }[\temp]
\global\let\ctext\temp
\endgroup
```

Comment: Is there a way to ... activate it? Or is there an equivalent way to do this using `enumerate` and `\csname`/`\endcsname`? (I tried and just got bizarre TeXy messages from `\StrSubstitute`.)

Comment: @SimonKuang Yes, I added it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now, just for the sake of my learning TeX, is there a simpler or more idiomatic way to build a list before printing it?

Comment: @SimonKuang It much depends on what you want to do.